# How to add a command to context menus in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: menu, command, visual-studio-2019, edit

I'm trying to add a command to the Document Tab context menu in Visual Studio 2019 so I can go directly to the open file in the Solution Explorer. I'm aware of File Tracking. I don't want to open the folder for every file tab I click on. I'm also aware of [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.FindinSolutionExplorer) but it seems like I have to click it two, sometimes three times before it will go to the file.

I found the relevant context menu under Customize -> Commands. It's "Other Context Menus | Easy MDI Document Window". The problem is that under "Add Command" you can only add from preselected lists of commands, and they don't make things easy to find.

I can see the command I want to add under Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. It's SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument. But I don't see any way to use it in the Customize window, or if it's there I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly add commands to a menu only from the existing VS menus.

For additional commands, you can create an intermediate command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/)  extension `DTE.ExecuteCommand("SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocumen")` and then add this VCmd.Command01 command to the menu.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to successfully create and run the macro, but VCmd isn't showing up under Customize->Commands->Add Command.

Comment: I figured it out. It was under Extensions.